# SWR NextJS error doesn't get handled after throwing

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, next.js, axios, swr

I am trying to handle the errors that get thrown in my SWR fetcher. Currently whenever I throw an error my app just stops working and I get an "Unhandled Runtime Error".

What I did was just throw the error inside the fetcher. Here is my code:

```
async function getFetcher(xxx: xxx) {
    const config = {
        params: {
            xxx: xxx
        },
    };

    return axios
        .get(url, config)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.data.error) {
                console.log("Error");

                throw new Error(response.data.error);
            } else {
                const data = response.data

                return data;
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("throwing error...");

            throw error;
        });
}

export function useFetcher(xxx: xxx) {
    const { data, error } = useSWR("/integrations/facebook/getAdSpend", (url: string) => getFetcher(xxx), {
        suspense: true,
    });

    if (error) {
        // NEVER GETS TO THIS POINT
        console.log("Error: " + error);
    }

    return {
        data: data,
        isLoadingData: !error && !data,
        error: error,
    };
}
```

I expected SWR to pick that error up and return it in the error variable. But it never even gets to the point where I can check the error variable, because my app just stops and displays the "Unhandled Runtime Error".

This is what I'm getting:
[image]

It's my first time working with SWR and errors in that way so I don't really know where to go from here.

Am I throwing it wrong? Why does SWR not handle it as expected?

EDIT:

This way I can catch and handle the error, but it is not passed as the error variable:

```
export function useFetcher(xxx: xxx) {
    const { data, error } = useSWR("/integrations/facebook/getAdSpend", (url: string) => getFetcher(xxx).catch((error) => {
        // The error thrown in the then block
        console.log(error);
    }), {
        suspense: true,
    });

    if (error) {
        // NEVER GETS TO THIS POINT
        console.log("Error: " + error);
    }

    return {
        data: data,
        isLoadingData: !error && !data,
        error: error,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is inside the `then` block of `getFetcher`

```
     if (response.data.error) {
         console.log("Error");

         throw new Error(response.data.error);
```

Why are you throwing error inside the `then` block? error handle is done inside `catch` block. if `catch` block catches an error this error will be passed to the `useSwr`.

Comment: Yeah, so I'm passing not-so-bad errors in the response with code 200. That's why I need to handle it in the then block.

But by throwing it gets forwarded to the catch block.
The line `console.log("throwing error...");` gets executed. So it is in the catch block after all.

But for some reason useSwr doesn't see that.

Comment: @Peter can you try `return error` instead of `throw error`

Comment: If I .catch the useSwr statement. I can catch the error thrown in the then block.

But it isn't passed to the error object. How would I get it to the error object?

Comment: If I do return error, the error is passed as the data object. As far as I know, anything that is returned is classified as data, and anything that is thrown is classified as error. Or at least that's how it is supposed to be

Comment: @Peter normally `throw` should work. but I cannot figure out what is causing the issue

Comment: Yeah its weird. I edited my question, if you wouldn't mind taking a look :)

Comment: It's working now. All I did was update the swr package.

Comment: same base code but updated version of `swr`